# Is there any better way to write blank if-else statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is there a better way to write this logic without making it too complicated to read?

```
    if(event.key === 'Enter' && !carIsOpen){
      if(event.ctrlKey){
        // Do nothing
      }else {
        return;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, invert it.

Comment: did you consider `if (!event.ctrlKey) return;`?

Comment: Just add an `!event.ctrlKey` to the first if condition, and return inside?

Comment: Why do you need an empty branch anyways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the second condition into the first if statement.

```
if (event.key === 'Enter' && !carIsOpen && !event.ctrlKey) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

I thik this is the best optimized way :

```
(condition) ? {what do do if true} : what to do if false;
```

in your case

```
(event.key==='Enter' && !carIsOpen && !event.ctrlKey)? return true : return false
```

Comment: Nooo! Ternary operator is not purposed to replace `if .. else` structure. Return the value the ternary returns instead.

Comment: ternary operators are meant to make your code cleaner ! The condition is an expression that evaluates to a Boolean value, either true or false. If the condition is true, the ternary operator returns expression_1, otherwise it returns the expression_2.

Comment: Exactly, and that's why you don't use a ternary like you've used in your answer.

Comment: try reading this documentation : https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-ternary-operator/

Comment: can you explain ? the condition is returning either true or false ? according to the result of the condition we either execute one statement or the other

Comment: It is a best practice to use the ternary operator when it makes the code easier to read.

Comment: There's no statements in an __operator__, that's the difference between clean code and that ... Operands are expected to be expressions.

Comment: quote "In this tutorial, you have learned how to use the JavaScript ternary operator that you can use as the shortcut of the if-else statement to make your code cleaner"

Comment: Please take a look at the examples of that tutorial, every example uses the value returned from the ternary, it is specifically not used to control program flow like `if .. else` can be used.

Comment: Again i quote "In this tutorial, you have learned how to **use the JavaScript ternary operator** that you can use as the shortcut of the **if-else statement** to make your code cleaner."

Comment: The tutorial doesn't propose to use ternary to control the program flow. You wouldn't expect a string concatenation suddenly exit a function, why would you expect a ternary operator to exit a function. That's not a clean use of a ternary. Statements are purposed to control the program, not the operators. The wording in that tutorial is just misleading. A correct use of the ternary in this case would be: `return (event.key==='Enter' && !carIsOpen && !event.ctrlKey) ? true : false;`.